# Stable partition in Numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

In essence, I need to do a stable partition: All elements of the 1D `np.array` `a` that are present in `b` should be moved to the front of `a` but apart from that, the relative order of the elements in `a` should be preserved.

This code seems to do what I want:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=np.int32)
    b = np.array([4, 2, 6],       dtype=np.int32)
    pos = np.in1d(a, b, assume_unique=True)
    cnt = np.count_nonzero(pos)
    tmp = np.empty(a.size, dtype=np.int32)
    tmp[0:cnt] = a[pos]
    tmp[cnt: ] = a[np.invert(pos)]
    a = tmp
    print('after stable partition:', a)
```

Output:

> ```
> after stable partition: [2 4 1 3 5]
> ```

Is there a cleaner / more efficient way of doing this in NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual creation of the `pos` mask looks perfect to me. You can streamline the rest of the code into a single-liner as:

```
a = np.concatenate((a[pos], a[~pos]))
```